# Fetching data using React Router and useLocation

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to trigger an api call each time a route is visited in react router. For example each time I route to `/list` The `List` component will call its API. It’s not possible to do this with `useEffect` when the component mounts because it’s not mounted each time the route is triggered. I am considering watching the location hook like so:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const location = useLocation()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // runs on location, i.e. route, change
    console.log('handle route change here', location)
  }, [location])
  ...
}
```

My issue is that if several components are watching the location then they will all have their useEffect triggered and call their APIs. I need to verify that this location is in fact the one that is currently displayed on the screen. I could use `location.pathName` to get the path but how do I verify this is the correct path for the component? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: could you add an If statement to figure out if the value is the one you expect before updating the components?

Comment: I could hardcore the route to the component yes. Just doesn’t seem very elegant.

Comment: well at some point you have to hardcode the value..... there is no escape from that.  but each component could handle it's own route.  also you could centralize the "listening" for the route change in a single place rather than in all the components.... may be a container?